# Save iframe content as XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, iframe

Lets assume that i put a valid xml string as the body of an iframe.

Is there any way to save it as an xml file from the client side. Like for example creating a link to the iframe, right-cclicking the link and choose "save target as" or something similar. Maybe using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to mess around with the `File` API: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: @LukeGT Thanks, but thats html5, right? Forgot to mention that it needs to work in ie7.

Comment: Yup that's HTML5.  In that case you might be able to find some IE-specific library to do it for you, but I'm not familiar with anything like that I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post back to server, and add `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1234.xml` header.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I believe there are security restrictions in place that preventthe  DOM from accessing contents within an iframe.